# Google Image Search keyboard shortcut

Tags: google-chrome

I was wondering what the Google Image keyboard shortcut is.

I thought there was shortcut to search for images; like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyboard shortcut is:

Right-click, then <kbd>S</kbd>

Comment: This doesn't work for me, did it change? Or what tab/position are u on to make this work..?